# How can I remove coordinates of points from lists if that are very close and and can be considered as a single point?

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison

I have 2 lists of numbers that represent points coordinates in a cartesian diagram.

**My aim is to consider many points in a range of 10 as 1 point.**

First example:

- first point (1,2)
- second point (2,3)
- third point (3,4)
- 4th point (80,90)

Coordinates list:

```
#(1)
x = [1,2,3, 80] 
Y = [2,3,4, 90 ]
```

I would like to delete the nearest point in a range of 10 (both in x and y), we could consider the first three numbers as a single one.

And result is:

```
x = [1, 80] and y = [2, 90]  or 
x = [2,80] and y = [3, 90] or 
x = [3,80] and y = [4, 90]
```

If coordinates lists are:

```
#(2)
x = [1,2,3, 80] 
Y = [2,3,70, 90 ]
```

we could consider the first 2 numbers as one

Result is:

```
x = [1, 80] and y = [2, 90]  or 
x = [2,80] and y = [3, 90] or
```

If they are:

```
#(3)
x = [1,2, 75, 78 , 80, 101] 
Y = [2,3, 81, 86, 90 , 91]
```

Result:

```
x = [1,75, 101] and y = [2,81, 91] or
x = [1,78, 101] and y = [2,86, 91] or
x = [1,80, 101] and y = [2,90, 91] or
x = [2,75, 101] and y = [3,81, 91] or
x = [2,78, 101] and y = [3,86, 91] or
x = [2,80, 101] and y = [3,90, 91] or
```

I need only 1 of this 6 solutions. It's not important if I have `x = [1,75]` or `x = [1,78]`.
The important thing is having close number as only one.

Last example:

```
x = [ 95, 154, 161, 135, 138, 116]
y = [158, 166, 168, 170, 170, 171]
```

In this case, only 3 points remain.

```
171 - 170 = 1  =>  138 - 116 = 22   both results are in the range of 25 i choose to delete 116 and 171


170 - 170 = 0  => 138 - 135 = 3 both result are in the range of 25 i delete 170 and 138

170 - 168 = 2  =>  135 - 161 = 26  i cannot delete

168 - 166 = 2 =>  161 - 154 = 7  i delete 168 and 161

166 - 158 = 8 =>  154 - 95 = 59 i cannot delete

x = [95, 154, 161, 135]
Y = [158, 166, 168, 170]
```

I repeat the operation and and I delete 161 in x and 168 in y because:
168 - 166 = 2 => 161 - 154 = 7

```
x = [95, 154, 135]
Y = [158, 166,  170]
```

`y` list is in ascending order.

What is the fastest way to compare them?

Comment: How did you get to `95` and `154`?

Comment: What does  “in a range of 10” mean?  Either explain things clearly or provide a couple more unrelated examples with completely different numbers

Comment: i correct text and result

Comment: What's the rule for why you don't delete that initial 95? What do you compare it against? Or do you just always keep the initial element?

Comment: By the way, why does your title ask for "the fastest way"? Do you actually mean fastest in terms of "Takes the least CPU time"? "Simplest to think through once you understand the basic concepts?" "Easiest to understand coming to programming from scratch?" "Fastest to type on a standard QWERTY keyboard?" "Requires the fewest drinks on a first date?"

Comment: i mean fastest in term of lines of code, cpu time, a good solution not the best at all. 95 is to be compared with the nearest, well in my example is not deleted because i compared him only with the second.

Comment: You state '168 - 166 = 2 =>  161 - 154 = 7  i delete 168 and 161' *before* you "repeat the operation", but you show y=168, x=161 in the results for the first pass instead of removing them! There should be only 3 points out of the first pass.

Comment: First, you can't mean both "lines of code" and "cpu time". Sure, sometimes you get lucky and the most efficient solution is also the shortest—but if not, which one is important to you? More importantly, why do you care about either of these? Is a 2-line function that you don't understand and can't debug or expand on better than a 4-line function that you do understand? Are you running this often enough that an extra 7 nanoseconds saved each time will add up to as much time as it took to type that sentence?

Comment: cpu time is priority , and i prefer few line of code because i do not wanna waste lines of code only for this procedure in program

Answer (score 5):

In general, it's easier to filter lists than to delete from them in-place.

But to filter easily, you need a single list, not two of them.

That's exactly what `zip` is for.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking for, because from the description it sounds like *everything* should stay except for 161 / 168. I'll show the rule it sounds like you were describing.

```
xy = zip(x, y)
new_xy = ((a, b) for a, b in xy if abs(a-b) <= 10)
x, y = zip(*new_xy)
```

Whatever your actual goal is, just replace the `if abs(a-b) <= 10` with the right rule for "if this pair of values should be kept", and you're done.

To understand how this works, you should try printing out `xy` (or, if you're using Python 3.x, `list(xy)`), and the other intermediate bits.

(If you're using Python 2.x, and your list are very big, you should probably `import itertools` and then use `xy = itertools.izip(x, y)` to avoid creating an extra list for no good reason. If you're using Python 3.x, this isn't a problem, because `zip` doesn't create extra lists anymore.)

---

From further comments, it seems like maybe you want to check `x[i]` against `x[i-1]`, not against `y[i]`, and in fact you don't look at the `y` values at all—it's just that if `x[i]` goes, so does `y[i]`.

To simplify things, let's take `y` out of the equation entirely, and just deal with filtering `x`. We can come back to the `y` later.

There are two ways to approach this. The first is to break down and build an explicit loop, where we keep track of a `last_value` each time through the loop. The second is to get a list of adjacent pairs within `x`.

The answer is, once again, `zip`:

```
x_pairs = zip(x, x[1:])
```

The only problem is that this doesn't give you anything to compare the first element to. For example:

```
>>> x = [95, 154, 161, 135, 138, 116]
>>> list(zip(x, x[1:]))
[(95, 154), (154, 161), (161, 135), (135, 138), (138, 116)]
```

That tells you whether or not to keep 154, 161, 135, 138, and 116… but what about that 95? Well, you never explained the rule for that. If you want to compare it to `0`, do `zip([0]+x, x)`. If you want to always keep it… you can just compare it to itself, so `zip(x[:1]+x, x)`. And so on. Whatever rule you want is pretty easy to write. I'll go with the "compare to `0`" rule.

So, now we've got these pairs of adjacent values `(95, 95)` then `(95, 154)`, and so on. In each case, if the distance between two adjacent values is `<= 10`, we want to keep the latter value. That's easy:

```
x_pairs = zip([0]+x, x)
new_x = [pair[1] for pair in x_pairs if abs(pair[0]-pair[1]) <= 10]
```

---

Putting the `y` in there is the same trick we used originally: just `zip` it to the pairs, and `zip` it back out afterward. To make things a bit simpler, instead of zipping the pairs and then zipping `y` on, we'll just `zip` it all up at once:

```
x_pairs_y = zip([0]+x, x, y)
new_xy = (xxy[1:] for xxy in x_pairs_y if abs(xxy[0]-xxy[1]) <= 10)
new_x, new_y = zip(*new_xy)
```

---

In some of your explanation, it sounds like you want to compare adjacent `x` values, and *also* compare adjacent `y` values, and filter them out if either different is >10.

If so, that's just more of the same:

```
xy_pairs = zip([0]+x, [0]+y, x, y)
new_xy = (xyxy[2:] for xyxy in xy_pairs 
          if abs(xyxy[0]-xyxy[2]) <= 10 and abs(xyxy[1]-xyxy[3]) <= 10)
new_x, new_y = zip(*new_xy)
```

However, when things get so complicated that your simple one-liners don't fit on one line, you should consider factoring things out a bit. For example, instead of having a list of `x` values and a list of `y` values, why not create a `Point` class?

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def long_diff(self, other):
        return max(abs(self.x-other.x), abs(self.y-other.y))
points = (Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(x, y))
point_pairs = zip([Point(0, 0)]+points, points)
new_points = (pair[1] for pair in point_pairs if pair[0].long_diff(pair[1]) <= 10)
new_x, new_y = zip(*((point.x, point.y) for point in points))
```

It's a bit longer, but a lot easier to understand.

And it would be even easier to understand if you just used a list of `Point` objects in the first place, instead of separate lists of `x` and `y` values.

---

From further comments, it sounds like the condition you want is the exact opposite of the condition shown in my last two examples, and you don't know how to negate a condition.

First, `not` takes any expression and returns the opposite truth value. So:

```
new_xy = (xyxy[2:] for xyxy in xy_pairs 
          if not(abs(xyxy[0]-xyxy[2]) <= 10 and abs(xyxy[1]-xyxy[3]) <= 10))
```

Alternatively, "delete if the x distance is <= 10 and the y distance is <= 10" is the same as "keep if the x distance is > 10 or the y distance is > 10", right? So:

```
new_xy = (xyxy[2:] for xyxy in xy_pairs 
          if abs(xyxy[0]-xyxy[2]) > 10 or abs(xyxy[1]-xyxy[3]) > 10)
```

---

Also, if you're sure that your sequences are always monotonically increasing (that is, any element is always larger than the one before it), you don't really need the `abs` here (as long as you make sure to get the operand order right).

Comment: I correct text and result, and i try your code. If i use <= 10 i get 161 in x and 168 in y but if the range is larger as 25 i get 2 numbers: (154, 161) for x and (166, 168) for y, But i would get the opposite: much larger is the range less point remain (much larger more i delete)

Comment: I invert sign from if abs(a-b) <= 10 to if abs(a-b) >= 10. Now much larger is the range less number i get as i want but if i try with range 25 i obtain for x (95, 135, 138, 116) and y (158, 170, 170, 171). 138 - 135 = 3 and 170 - 170 = 0.  0 and 3 are less than 25 why are not deleted?

Comment: @improc: I'm sorry, I don't understand your questions. Are you saying that you don't know the difference between `<= 10` and `> 10`? And meanwhile, you seem to have switched from comparing `x[i]` vs. `y[i]` to `x[i]` vs. `x[i+1]` somewhere in the middle there. You can do that too, but… how do you keep `x` and `y` in sync in that case? More simply, how do they end up the same length at the end? In fact, how are they related _at all_?

Comment: I'm sorry for not having explained well, i would like to compare adjacent x values first basing on 10 (in this case) as distance, in case distance between x and x-1 is less than 10 i check also their y values. if also y value is less then 10 i filter, delete x and y value. The result is good as a list of point objects that two coordinate lists

Comment: Ah,about <= 10 and > 10 i'm saying that much larger is the range less points remain, smaller is the range much  points remains and in your first example the opposite happened

Comment: I try with these 2 lists: x = [ 1,2,3, 80] y = [2,3,4 ,90] and your procedure delete 80 in x and 90 y! That is supposed to be the only value that must not be deleted because there is nothing in a range of 10. In this case i expect one of this 3 solutions: [1,80] or [2,80] or [3,80] for x

Comment: @improc: OK, you want to delete if both are <= 10. That means you want to keep is either is > 10. So, just change the `abs(xyxy[0]-xyxy[2]) <= 10 and abs(xyxy[1]-xyxy[3]) <= 10)` to `abs(xyxy[0]-xyxy[2]) > 10 or abs(xyxy[1]-xyxy[3]) > 10)`. Or, alternatively, just do `not(abs(xyxy[0]-xyxy[2]) <= 10 and abs(xyxy[1]-xyxy[3]) <= 10))`. This is elementary stuff, and if you can't figure it out, you need to start off with something simpler.

Comment: There was a misunderstanding! I changed from <10 to >10 by myself but if you take this example. x = [ 1,2,3, 80] y = [2,3,4 ,90] it delete all numbers 1,2,3 and remain only x = [80] and y = [90], but my aim is to consider many points in a range of 10 like 1 point , so in this case that we have 4 points after the operation i would like to have only 2 points: 1 has coordinates x = 80 and y =90 and the other has coordinate or (1,2) or (2,3) or (3,4).

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure why you "repeat the operation", or when to stop, so I have coded it up so the operation repeats until no more points are removed. Intermediate points are shown in order in a list as a two-element tuple of (x, y) coordinates rather than separate lists of x and y.

```
def outrange(pts, rnge):
    partial = pts[::-1]  # current points in reverse order
    i, lastp = 0, []
    while lastp != partial:
        print('%i times around we have: %r' % (i, partial[::-1]))
        i, lastp, partial = (i+1, 
                            partial, 
                            [(pn1x, pn1y) 
                            for (pnx, pny), (pn1x, pn1y) in zip(partial[1:], partial) 
                            if abs(pn1x - pnx) > rnge or abs(pn1y - pny) > rnge
                            ] + partial[-1:])
    return partial[::-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    j = 0
    for rnge, x, y in [(10, [1, 2, 3, 80] , [2, 3, 4, 90 ]),
                        (10, [1, 2, 3, 80] , [2, 3, 70, 90 ]),
                        (10, [1,2, 75, 78 , 80, 101], [2,3, 81, 86, 90 , 91]),
                        (25, [ 95, 154, 161, 135, 138, 116], [158, 166, 168, 170, 170, 171])]:
        j += 1
        print('\n## Example %i: Points outside range %s of:' % (j, rnge))
        print('  x = %r\n  y = %r' % (x, y))
        pts = [(xx, yy) for xx, yy in zip(x,y)]
        ans_x, ans_y = [list(z) for z in zip(*outrange(pts, rnge))]
        print('  Answer: x = %r\n          y = %r' % (ans_x, ans_y))
```

The output is:

```
## Example 1: Points outside range 10 of:
  x = [1, 2, 3, 80]
  y = [2, 3, 4, 90]
0 times around we have: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (80, 90)]
1 times around we have: [(1, 2), (80, 90)]
  Answer: x = [1, 80]
          y = [2, 90]

## Example 2: Points outside range 10 of:
  x = [1, 2, 3, 80]
  y = [2, 3, 70, 90]
0 times around we have: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 70), (80, 90)]
1 times around we have: [(1, 2), (3, 70), (80, 90)]
  Answer: x = [1, 3, 80]
          y = [2, 70, 90]

## Example 3: Points outside range 10 of:
  x = [1, 2, 75, 78, 80, 101]
  y = [2, 3, 81, 86, 90, 91]
0 times around we have: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (75, 81), (78, 86), (80, 90), (101, 91)]
1 times around we have: [(1, 2), (75, 81), (101, 91)]
  Answer: x = [1, 75, 101]
          y = [2, 81, 91]

## Example 4: Points outside range 25 of:
  x = [95, 154, 161, 135, 138, 116]
  y = [158, 166, 168, 170, 170, 171]
0 times around we have: [(95, 158), (154, 166), (161, 168), (135, 170), (138, 170), (116, 171)]
1 times around we have: [(95, 158), (154, 166), (135, 170)]
2 times around we have: [(95, 158), (154, 166)]
  Answer: x = [95, 154]
          y = [158, 166]
```

The algorithm did what you did as noted in your explanation for example 4, but I questioned your logic in a comment to the main question as you say you drop a point then show it in the intermediate step.

If you calculated other results that are different to mine then please state why you get your differenc, i.e. what it is in your algorithm that I have not done, or look *carefully* at your answer for mistakes.

Comment: My aim is to consider many points in a range of 10 like 1 point , so  if you take this example: x = [ 1,2,3, 80] y = [2,3,4 ,90]  we have 4 points and after the operation i would like to have only 2 points. 1 has coordinates x = 80 and y =90 and the other has coordinate or (1,2) or (2,3) or (3,4).

Comment: it's really a good job! Your code works very well! And yes, the operation has to be repeats until no more points are removed!

Comment: I tried this sequence:     x = [3, 80, 5,  51, 52,  53]  y = [1,  2,  3,  50, 51, 82]    and the answer was:   Answer: x = [3, 80, 5, 51, 53] y = [1, 2, 3, 50, 82] .  (3,1) is near (5,3)! one of them must be removed

Comment: @improc, what was the range? Remember though that if it doesn't do what you want it to do then it may be the algorithm you described. For example, it could be because the algorithm may depend on the initial ordering of the points in a way you have not considered.

Comment: Range is 10, yes i think depend by the order or because it doesn't check x value. If you check that 1,2 and 3 we can see that they are in a range of 10 , the second step is to check also x 3,80 and 5. I have to be careful that there is no number in the list next to another number in a range of 10. Now i see that my algorithm is not correct because if i check only the nearest position, also with y ascendent, i do not have what i want